# What is the logic behind this code and how it is working?

Tags: .net, vb.net

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub btn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnZero.Click, btnTwo.Click, btnThree.Click, btnSix.Click, btnSeven.Click, btnOne.Click, btnNine.Click, btnFour.Click, btnFive.Click, btnEight.Click
        Dim btnNumber As Button = sender
        If lblResult.Text = ("0") Then
            lblResult.Text = btnNumber.Text
        Else
            lblResult.Text = lblResult.Text + btnNumber.Text
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

I'm working on a simple calculator and I don't understand this logic here's the reference btw: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iMgTPKEFRMI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Privat Sub btn_Click(sender As Object` ...
is an event handler.

`sender` is the control that received the Click event.

Since this handler is set up with a whole list of controls that could have received the event, we can use the the `text` property to determine which one was clicked.

The starting value of the label `lblResult.text` is "0". So, if that is all that is in the label we will replace the value in the label's text property with the Text of the button that was clicked.

If a button has already been clicked the label will not have "0" anymore. In this case the `Else` portion will kick in and the label will append the text of the clicked button to whatever is there already.

You could write this program with an event handler for every button on your calculator and repeat the `If...Else` code but this would be a great deal of typing. Having one handler is shorter for you to write and will behave the same.

Answer (score 0):

When the button is clicked the result label will either be reset to the text of `btnNumber` or the text of `btnNumber` will be appended.

Answer (score 0):

When any of the buttons among `btnZero, btnTwo, btnThree, btnSix, btnSeven, btnOne, btnNine, btnFour, btnFive, btnEight' is clicked for the first time, then this block is executed :

```
If lblResult.Text = ("0") Then
   lblResult.Text = btnNumber.Text
```

It means the text of the `Label lblResult` is set to any number between `0-9` based on the clicked button. For example, if `btnFive` is clicked, then the text of `lblResult` will be `5` if this button's text property is `5`. If the buttons is clicked but not the first time then `Else` block will be executed. Again for example, if `btnFour` is clicked assuming you clicked 'btnFive' before it, then the text of `lblResult` will be `54` if this button's text property is `4`. Again if you click `btnOne`, the it will be `541` and so on. Hope this helps you to understand the code.